# Installing PHP 7.4.2 on OSX

Tags: php

I am following the usual `./configure`, `make` , `sudo make install` process to install PHP 7.4.2. Unfortunately some files were missing. This are the commands:

`./configure` reports an error

```
checking for libxml-2.0 >= 2.7.6... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libxml-2.0 >= 2.7.6) were not met:

No package 'libxml-2.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBXML_CFLAGS
and LIBXML_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

So I installed libxml2 using `brew install libxml2` and also ran `brew install homebrew/core/libiconv` along the way.

I than ran `./configure LIBXML_CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include LIBXML_LIBS=-L/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib --with-iconv=$(brew --prefix libiconv)`

which completed successfully.

Unfortunatly, `make` complains of an error

```
/Users/mainuser/Downloads/php-7.4.2/ext/libxml/libxml.c:34:10: fatal error: 'libxml/parser.h' file not
      found
#include <libxml/parser.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [ext/libxml/libxml.lo] Error 1
```

There is indeed no `./ext/libxml/parser.h present`.

What am I missing? Any ideas on how to fix this?

There is symlink in `/usr/local/opt/libxml2` that points to `/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.10` which is where `brew` put `libxml2`. I can see the parser.h file there, but apparently compiler is not picking it up.